# How can I view os_log log entries as they stream from a device using the log tool?

Tags: ios, logging, oslog

This is a question about Apple’s unified logging and activity tracing system, sometimes known as `os_log`.

I have an app that will not run in the simulator, but only on device. I want to use `os_log` to emit logs. I want to view the live stream of logs, not in the Console app, but with the `log` command line tool, since it provides a more flexible interface for filtering log messages. Is there a way to do this?

A way to view the *stream* of logs (not files), from a *device* (not the Simulator), which were created by calls to `os_log` (not some other system)?